# Why cant I download OpenSUSE With Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, downloads

I recently thought in changing to Linux, putted a disc with Ubuntu in my PC and booted it, then installed Ubuntu and now i want to download OpenSUSE.iso.

The problem is: The download fails and i cant retry because when I try it Ubuntu scans for a split second and then says it failed again.
 (Using Ubuntu  14.04)

Comment: Did you delete the "half downloaded" iso file before trying again? Is there enough disk space left? Does the user you logged in as have write permissions on the directory you tried to store the iso file in?

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu to my Hard Drive because i thought about the disk space issue, but that is not the case. Yes I have permissions and i did try delete the file but nothing of that worked, thanks for answering

Comment: What happens if you try to delete the broken file? What are the permissions of the broken file and of the directory it is in? What user are they owned by, respectively? Please edit your question with the output of the following commands (you may need to adjust your filenames and paths)

`ls -l /home/username/Downloads/the-iso-file.iso' (information about the broken file)
'ls -l /home/username/Downloads' (information about the directory it is stored in)
'df -h' (information about your partitions and the storage space left on them)

Comment: If wget doesn't work i will share that information, but I'm not sure if it's safe to say that data (Also I'm very new to Linux and its the first time I'm messing arround with the terminal, so I'm having a hard time putting those commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have problems with a download that is hanging or being interrupted, you can download the OpenSUSE iso file (or any other file) from the terminal using the built-in `wget` program. Select a mirror that is both close to you and also seems unlikely to be too slow or interrupted.

Here is how to ensure that you will have a successfully completed download. Open the terminal. Change directories using the `cd` command to a directory where you can easily find the OpenSUSE iso file after you have downloaded it. For example to change directories to your desktop use the command: `cd ~/Desktop/`. Next run the following command:

```
wget -c 'download-link-of-OpenSUSE-iso-file'
```

where you replace `download-link-of-OpenSUSE-iso-file` with the link of the OpenSUSE iso file that you want to download. The `-c` flag in `wget -c` will enable the download to continue from the same place it was stopped if it is paused or interrupted. Unless you stop the download manually, it will resume the download automatically from the same place in the file where the download was interrupted. You can even pause the download and continue the download from a different mirror from the same place it was stopped, in case the first mirror that you selected is downloading the file too slowly. For example, if you intend to download the *openSUSE-13.2-DVD-x86_64.iso* file here is that file's worldwide [Mirror List](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/iso/openSUSE-13.2-DVD-x86_64.iso?mirrorlist), and you can be sure that some of the mirrors on the list are much faster than others.

Comment: I am downloading it right now, I'll give more information about how it went later. (Downloading 32bit version)

Comment: `wget` provides information about the progress of a file being downloaded which can be used to check if your file is being downloaded fast enough.

Comment: Its arround 1.5 / 2MB/s (same as it was in Firefox ) can I try make a download in other mirror to see if it is faster ??

Comment: If your download speed is 1.5MB/sec then it will take about 11 minutes to download  1 GB which isn't very long to wait, and you could download 4GB at that speed in less than an hour. When I need to download a large file, I usually choose the closest mirror and start the download late at night when very few users would be using that mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Two interesting programs, ***wget*** and ***aria2***. Although I would recommend ***aria2***. *Aria2* can download a file from multiple sources/protocols and tries to utilize your maximum download bandwidth. Really speeds up your download experience.

1. Open the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Pick a mirror from [this](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/iso/openSUSE-13.2-DVD-x86_64.iso?mirrorlist) list
3. Download the file with a download manager:

   - **aria2**

     Interrupted downloads automatically continue

     Can download a file from multiple sources/protocols and tries to utilize your maximum download bandwidth

     - Install *aria2*

       ```
       sudo apt-get install aria2
       ```

     *EXAMPLE*

     - Start a download with this command:

       ```
       aria2c -x2 http://ftp.uni-kl.de/pub/linux/opensuse/distribution/13.2/iso/openSUSE-13.2-DVD-x86_64.iso
       ```

       The `-x` option specified the number of allowed connections, while the `-k` option specified the size of chunks.
   - **wget**

     *EXAMPLE*

     - Start a download with this command:

       ```
       wget --continue http://ftp.uni-kl.de/pub/linux/opensuse/distribution/13.2/iso/openSUSE-13.2-DVD-x86_64.iso
       ```

       from `man wget`:

       ```
       --continue
       Continue getting a partially-downloaded file.  This is useful when you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of Wget, or by another program.
       ```

Comment: You shouldn't put that mirror because it may not be the ideal for me, and I'm pretty sure -c is the same as --continue. Still its very similar to karel post

Comment: @DuarteDdias I'ts an example as you can read.

Comment: @DuarteDdias I think that having this as a separate answer with a concrete example will likely help others who see this, even if karel's answer is entirely sufficient for your needs. (The related chat discussion [starts here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21331920#21331920).) In addition to helping the specific individuals who ask questions, [creating a reusable resource for others](https://askubuntu.com/tour) is integral to the purpose of Ask Ubuntu; I believe having these two answers, with different approaches and presentations, helps with that.

Comment: @DuarteDdias I think aria2 is the better choice.